# Jupyter run command with redirect fails: run(`cat tmp.csv >> other.csv`)

Tags: python, shell, redirect, jupyter

I'm trying to combine text files in a Jupyter notebook (exported dataframes text, now trying to join them).
When I use the 'run' command with backticks, it doesn't seem to allow append to file. Strangely, it does the 'cat' portion to stdou, and then fails when it sees the redirect. I've tried backslashes before the gt symbols and other escaping, but can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas on how to get this to work? (btw, there are backticks before the 'cat' and after the last csv.. might not come though in formatting though.

```
run(`cat tmp.csv >> other.csv`)

"A","B"
1,4
2,5
cat: '>>': No such file or directory
failed process: Process(`cat tmp.csv >> other.csv`, ProcessExited(1)) [1]

 in run at ./process.jl:531
```

Comment: At least in Ipython, `run` is used to run python scripts.  '!' is used to run shell commands.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj . I am using the `run` command, but it doesn't seem to like when I use a redirect. So cat tmp.csv will work, but cat tmp.csv >> other.csv will fail. Maybe some sort of pre-processor error where I need to escape something out (??)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `!` to run shell commands in Jupyter Notebook.

```
!cat tmp.py >> other.py
```